# Scatterplot Matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Here is the script I am working with:

```
data(mtcars, package= "datasets")

diacars <- subset(mtcars,select = c(mpg,disp,hp,drat,wt,qsec))
summary(diacars)

corMat <- cor(diacars, method= "pearson")
round(corMat,2)

car::scatterplotMatrix(~mpg+disp+hp+drat+wt+qsec, data=diacars, diagonal="density", 
                       smoother=gamLine)

corrplot::corrplot(corMat, col=colors, method="ellipse", order="FPC",
                   diag=FALSE, addCoef.col="green")
```

The focus is on this part:

```
car::scatterplotMatrix(~mpg+disp+hp+drat+wt+qsec, data=diacars, diagonal="density", 
                       smoother=gamLine)
```

The scatterplot matrix is supposed to look like this:

[Correct Scatterplot Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NygbG.png)

But it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look into varying the `smoother.args` arguments for gamLine. Please refer to the following link `https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/2.1-5/topics/ScatterplotSmoothers`, and play with the arguments. You should find the answer hopefully.